# Browser showing scrollbar for long text despite max-width

Tags: html, css

Why does this HTML cause a scrollbar to appear?

```html
<div style="width: 200px; max-width: 200px; background-color: lightblue;">
verylongtext_verylongtext_verylongtext_verylongtext_verylongtext_verylongtext_verylongtext_verylongtext_verylongtext_verylongtext_verylongtext_verylongtext_
</div>
```

I think it should not because I have specified a maximum width. I expected there to be *no* wrapping but also *no* scrollbar because the final width of the div is 200px.

I can't use `overflow: hidden;` because my website actually makes use of rendering widgets outside of its containing element using relative positioning.

How can I contain that text or at least prevent the scrollbar from appearing? It is acceptable to render that text outside of its parent.

Comment: Why not push the widgets behind with z-index?

Answer (score 1):

Use `word-wrap: break-word;` because there is no space between text so it won't break in new line and it will ignore `max-width`

```html
<div style="width: 200px; max-width: 200px;word-wrap: break-word; background-color: lightblue;">
verylongtext_verylongtext_verylongtext_verylongtext_verylongtext_verylongtext_verylongtext_verylongtext_verylongtext_verylongtext_verylongtext_verylongtext_
</div>
```

Comment: Is there no way to keep it as it is? I also wonder *why* this behavior occurs.

Comment: It occurs because the default word wrap is to break on space.  Since there is no white space the text does not break. If there is no break, then the browser will add a scroll bar.

Comment: If there is no space between characters HTML will take it as single word and it wont't break it in new/next line.

Comment: `max-width` only defining the limit of element's width, it will not hide overflowing content of it until you hide it by `overflow:hidden`.

Comment: I don't care about hiding it. I care about understanding why the scrollbar appears and how exactly the browser decides to do that.

Comment: As I told you, max-width is setting limited width of element, and HTML is taking that text (without whitespace) as a word and HTML will not break it, that's why it's overflowing element, even though you set max-width it will still create scroll bar

Comment: What does `width` mean? Apparently it does not mean "this exact width".

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div style="width: 200px; max-width: 200px; background-color: lightblue;">
verylongtext_verylongtext_verylongtext_verylongtext_verylongtext_verylongtext_verylongtext_ verylongtext_verylongtext_verylongtext_verylongtext_verylongtext_
</div>
```

Comment: browsers consider your sentence as only one word and they don't cut word then they generate automaticaly **margin-right**, in snippet  result  change because i put space in text **( space between words)** even if you use bootstrap grid with that you will obtain the same result

Comment: Why does the width setting not take?

Comment: it's not take because in this case priority here  is your device width that browser use unless you decrease your  **font-size** you can resolve this problem too with css properties **word-wrap : break-word** refer to [word-break](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) for learn more , i hope to have  help you